# Замена строк в js файле при помощи c#

Tags: javascript, c#, регулярные-выражения

Доброе время суток. Прошу помочь разобраться с реализацией замены строк в .js файле.
Строки имеют следующей вид:

```
user_pref("mail.server.server1.port", 992);
user_pref("mail.smtpserver.smtp1.port", 583);
user_pref("mail.smtpserver.smtp1.username", "test150");
```

Замену строк делаю следующим образом

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(configuration, @"Filename.js", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var item in allfiles)
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(item);
            content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(\w|\.)*?ExampleEmail1\.(ru|lan)", @"@ExampleEmail2.ru", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            content = Regex.Replace(content, @"user_pref(""mail.server.server1.port"", 992)", @"user_pref(""mail.server.server1.port"", 100)");
            if (File.Exists(item + ".old") == false)
                File.Copy(item, item + ".old");
            File.WriteAllText(item, content);
        }
```

В первой строке content где я меняю имя почты все предельно ясно и работает, но когда пытаюсь заменить сроки отвечающие за порт и т.п ничего не выходит. 
Хочу в файле менять всю строчку целиком, как мне это реализовать ?

Comment: `(` и `)` надо экранировать, `\(` и `\)`, также как и точки. `Regex.Replace(content, @"user_pref\(""mail\.server\.server1\.port"", 992\)", "user_pref(\"mail.server.server1.port\", 100)")`. А зачем вам вообще тут регулярное выражение? Вы хотели подставить `\d{2,3}` вместо `992`?

Comment: регулярное выражение использую потому что не знаю какой именно порт будет выставлен в настройках. Хотел выставить другой порт вместо 992 порт 25 или 897 к примеру.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(content, @"user_pref\(""mail\.server\.server1\.port"", \d{2,}\)", "user_pref(\"mail.server.server1.port\", 100)")`?

Comment: зачем делать замену внутри строки, если можно заменить сразу строку целиком?

Comment: Сделать массив строк которые мне нужны, а после просто циклом пройтись и заменить их?

Comment: Объясните в вопросе, что вы делаете и что вам надо.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew В вопросе исправил. Сделал следующим образом. content = Regex.Replace(content, "user_pref\\(\"mail\\.smtpserver\\.smtp1\\.port\",\\s*\\d+\\);", "user_pref(\"mail.smtpserver.smtp1.port\", 587);");

Comment: Т.е. любой порт надо заменить на 587?

Comment: Нет. В описании вопроса я добавил "Хочу в файле менять всю строчку целиком, как мне это реализовать ?". Поэтому ту строчку которую мне нужно заменить я меняю уже сразу с правильным портом. Остальные строки в которых может быть указан порт остаются неизменными. Ваш первый комментарий правильно указал на мою ошибку, я совершенно не подумал об экранировании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки `(` и `)` надо экранировать, `\(` и `\)`, также как и точки (`.` => `\.`). Неэкранированные символы `(` и `)` задают *захватывающую подмаску*, а `.` находит любой символ, кроме перехода на новую строку (с опцией `RegexOptions.Singleline` находит любые символы).

Чтобы найти любые 1 и более цифр, используйте `\d+`.

**Решение**:

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(content, 
     @"user_pref\(""mail\.server\.server1\.port"", \d+\)", 
      "user_pref(\"mail.server.server1.port\", 587)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Так и не понял ты хочешь поменять всю строку целиком или отдельно порт отдельно сервер?
Если целиком то:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"user_pref(.*)", @"user_pref(""mail.server.server1.port"", 100)");
```